# How to summarise factor columns according to the group_by of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of let's say 3 factor columns: cluster, sex, vaccination. I would like to obtain the summary of the sex and vaccination columns grouped by the cluster column in an "automatic" way and not one by one.

For example to get just one of them this worked:

```
cluster <- sample(1:4, 1, size = 20)
set.seed(10)
sex <- sample(0:1, 1, size = 20)
set.seed(20)
vaccine <- sample(0:1, 1, size = 20)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(cluster,sex,vaccine))
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.factor))
df %>% 
  group_by(cluster, sex) %>% 
  summarize(count = n())
```

but this would mean I would have to write this for every variable (in the real code there will be 40 factors from which I am interested to obtain the summary). I also tried this to do it automatically for all variables:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), count = n()))
```

but this gives me the following error

Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(everything(), count = n())`.
ℹ In group 1: `cluster = 1`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• count = n()

is there any way of obtaining the count or percentage of all the other factor columns grouped by one column? (my desired output would look like this, or with the percentage for each category)

[image]
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have any sample data?

Comment: Could you please include `set.seed()` and your expected output from this sample data? i.e. what would the output look like for say 2 or 3 variables. Are you wanting to group by `cluster` and `sex`, then `sex` and `vaccine`, and separately by `vaccine` and `cluster`?

Comment: Updated! I want in all the summaries to take into account the cluster and then combine cluster with just one variable but repeat it for all the variables. In the example above the results are for cluster and sex on the one side and for cluster and vaccine on the other

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach, but it only works because there are equal number of factors in the `sex` and `vaccine` variables. If there is a variable with a different number of factors in your data set the call to `list_cbind` will fail due to differing number of rows.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


set.seed(10)
cluster <- sample(1:4, 1, size = 20)
sex <- sample(0:1, 1, size = 20)
vaccine <- sample(0:1, 1, size = 20)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(cluster,sex,vaccine))
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.factor))

# function to calculate the counts by variable, this assumes that `cluster` will be a grouping variable in all cases.
# `arrange(cluster)` ensures that resultant data frames are in the same row order provided that the number of factor levels for each variable is the same.

fun <- function(var){

  # create a summary variable name based on the input variable name
  sum_var <- paste0("count_", as.name(var))
  
  df1 <- 
    df |>
    summarise(!!sum_var := n(), .by = c(cluster, {{var}})) |> 
    arrange(cluster)
  
  return(df1)
  
  }

# vector for all other names in the data set
arg1 = names(df)[-1]

# use purrr::map to loop through the variables and bind the resulting  dataframes. Finally a bit of tidying up to remove the duplicated cluster columns. 
 
map(arg1, fun) |> 
  list_cbind() |> 
  rename(cluster = cluster...1) |> 
  select(-starts_with("cluster..."))

#> New names:
#> • `cluster` -> `cluster...1`
#> • `cluster` -> `cluster...4`
#>   cluster sex count_sex vaccine count_vaccine
#> 1       1   1         1       1             1
#> 2       1   0         1       0             1
#> 3       2   1         4       1             3
#> 4       2   0         1       0             2
#> 5       3   0         6       0             3
#> 6       3   1         2       1             5
#> 7       4   0         3       1             2
#> 8       4   1         2       0             3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try `merge`ing the resulting list of tibbles. Using an asymmetric data set for illustration.

`colnames(df)[-1]` excludes *cluster*, leaving *sex* and *vaccine* for counting.

```
library(dplyr)

setNames(purrr::reduce(lapply(colnames(df)[-1], \(x) 
           df %>% 
             group_by(cluster, !!rlang::sym(x)) %>% 
             count()), merge, by=1:2, all=T), 
  c(colnames(df)[1], "values", paste0(colnames(df)[-1], "_count")))
  cluster values sex_count vaccine_count
1       1      0         1             4
2       1      1         4             1
3       2      0         4             2
4       2      1         1             3
5       3      0         5             5
6       3      1         3             3
7       4      0        NA             1
8       4      1         2             1
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(cluster = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), vaccine = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```